# VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews by using react native SearchableDropdown

Tags: react-native, autocomplete, flatlist

How to use `scrollview` over package like react-native-autocomplete-input? Basically I have a form in my react native package in which there are multiple input fields including autocomplete so I need a scroll over my screen so how should I achieve that?My code looks like that

```
<ScrollView>
 <Card>
  <TextInput />
  <SearchableDropdown />
  <TextInput />
  <Picker />
 </Card>
</Scrollview>
```

It gives me that error

```
VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality
```

Comment: Does your content not fit all inside one screen without scrolling?

Comment: no, it was just a sample code actually i have a lot of input text